# How to simplify $A(\overline BC+B)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do I go from $A(\overline BC+B)$ to $A(B+C)$? What definition should I use to get the final answer?

Would like an explanation and proof so I can learn rather than just memorise.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle\bar BC+B=\bar BC+B\cdot1=\bar BC+B(1+C)$ as $1+C=1$

$\displaystyle\implies \bar BC+B=C(B+\bar B)+B=C\cdot1+B=C+B$

Comment: Ahh thanks, makes sense.

Comment: I'm confused, in what kind of algebra does $1+C = 1$ if we know nothing about $C$??

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, In Boolean algebra $C=1$ or $0$ and $0+1=1=1+1,$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : ah, so I interpret $+$ as a union, not as a modulo $2$ thing. Okay

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I maintained the notations used by OP. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : It's an algebra, you can write $+$ as $+$ and $\cdot$ as $\cdot$! I just wasn't aware of what they meant. It's fine :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Beware that a "Boolean algebra" is not an "algebra" (in the sense of a ring that is simultaneously a module). Using additive notation for the join operator can be confusing because Boolean algebras are in one-to-one correspondence with Boolean _rings_, and the ring addition (which _is_ a modulo 2 thing) does not correspond to the Boolean-algebra join.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If this doesn't make a lengthy discussion, how do you perform this correspondence? I didn't manage to look it up.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Given a Boolean algebra $(A,{\land},{\lor},{\neg},0,1)$ you get a Boolean ring by defining $x\cdot y = x\land y$ and $x+y = (x\lor y)\land \neg(x\land y)$. Conversely given a Boolean ring (i.e. a ring where $x^2=x$ for all $x$), you can make a Boolean algebra by defining $x\land y=xy$, $x\lor y=x+y-xy$, and $\neg x=1-x$. [Wikipedia has a good discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring).

Answer (score 0):

use the distributive law
$$(B'C+B)=(B+B').(B+C)$$
also 
$$B+B'=1$$